# Is this SQL (oracle) query correct?

Tags: sql, oracle

Diagram of Tables:

[image: Diagram of Tables]

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.location, tb.num_students_enrolled, tb2.num_sections
FROM section s 
    JOIN
    (SELECT location, COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) num_students_enrolled
    FROM section sec JOIN enrollment e ON(sec.section_id = e.section_id)
    GROUP BY location) tb
ON(s.location = tb.location)
    JOIN
    (SELECT location, COUNT(section_id) num_sections
    FROM section sect
    GROUP BY location) tb2
ON(s.location = tb2.location)
ORDER BY s.location
```

**Question:**
Create a query that lists location, number of sections taught in that location and number of students enrolled in courses at that location. Sort by location.

*Enrollment table* - many to many relationship between section_id and student_id. A student can be enrolled in multiple sections, and there can be multiple students enrolled in a section.
Section Table

*Section table* - section_id is unique primary key. There are a total of 12 locations.

**Query Results**

```
location nm_st_en nm_sects   
    H310    1        1
    L206    8        1
    L210    29       10
    L211    10       3
    L214    33       15
    L500    14       2
    L507    33       15
    L509    64       25
    L511    3        1
    M200    1        1
    M311    11       3
    M500    5        1
```

Comment: What is wrong with the results that you are currently getting, and which results do you expect?

Comment: I'm just not to sure if it is calculations are properly done. When I use DISTINCT for the COUNT in the tb table it returns less results in some rows than without it.

Comment: You would probably need to build a small but representative dataset that you could use for testing. If you get the wrong results, then you could provide the dataset with your question, along with your expected results.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of tables. These should be included by putting the DDL statement required to build the tables into your question as [code-formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Expecting people to create the DDL for 10 tables so we can answer your question is overly optimistic. Make it easy for people to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the query is correct requires data, and is up to you to figure out. Write some queries to verify your results on a subset of the data.

But I think you might be over-complicating this.

Something like:

```
select sec.location, 
       count(distinct sec.section_id) as number_of_sections, 
       count(distinct enr.student_id) as number_of_students
from Section sec join Enrollment enr on sec.section_id = enr.section_id
group by sec.location
order by sec.location;
```

As a general pointer, you should avoid joining query results, as it makes things a bit difficult to understand. Also, parenthesis around join clauses are unnecessary clutter.